# Pandas Dataframe column search and replace char(34) " and char(39) '

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using python with flask and try to store data in a mysql database.

Hope someone can help me, I try to clean a pandas dataframe column df['WERT'] from char(34) " and char(39) ' and upload these values into a mysql table.

in this column is for example the value 
'ZAST_DIR','6.3'

Error Message: is ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;

I know I have to get rid of char(34) and char(39)

I tried a few things:

```
df['WERT'] = df['WERT'].str.replace("'", '')
```

or

```
df['WERT'].replace(to_replace=["\'", '\"'], value=' ', inplace=True)
```

Thank you in advance for your help and time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think need `regex=True` for replace substrings:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'WERT':['"aaa"', "'sdsd"]})
df['WERT'].replace(to_replace=["'", '"'], value='', inplace=True, regex=True)
```

Alternative solution:

```
df['WERT'] = df['WERT'].str.replace("'", '').str.replace('"', '')
```

---

```
print (df)
   WERT
0   aaa
1  sdsd
```

Comment: thank you. Your example is working. But unfortenately not in my dataframe.

Comment: @aeaeae - Maybe some another character?

Comment: there was also a : sign. But still there is a failure. I try to filter the df before and after the replace.

Comment: sorry i can't upvote your answer -> the replacement worked well --> there was another error in the csv file :(